# How can I implement permission-based authorization in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, authorization, custom-attributes

I'm working an a ASP.NET application (not using MVC) and need a User-Role-Permission based authorization scheeme, where pages and/or methods can demand the specific permission they require (instead of which role the user has). Is there a way to extend Forms Authentication (or building something) to solve this?

If possible I would like to be able to use attributes:

```
[RequirePermission("UserEdit")]
public partial class EditUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}
```

Perhaps even for methods:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    [RequirePermission("UserEdit")]
    public void Save()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

I found [this page](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/PermissionbasedAuthorizationVsRolebasedAuthorization.aspx), that suggested using Roles for permissions:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "UserEdit")]
public partial class EditUser : System.Web.UI.Page
{
}
```

I am not *very* fond of this solution, but that would also be a possible way to solve things, but what do I need to do to get it working?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the difference between what you're looking for and what the `AuthorizeAttribute` already provides. What don't you like about `AuthorizeAttribute`?

Comment: @qntmfred: Roles based authorization is not Permission based authorization. Microsoft simplified everything to Roles based authorization in their IPrincipal model...but this is widely acknowledged as terrible design on their part. The ideal model includes Users, Roles, AND Permissions. Users are in Roles. Roles have sets of Permissions.

Comment: like Rocky (and you as well) said though...if you consider that IsInRole() can be thought of as "HasPermission()", then there's a solution. When you load the .NET principal with a list of "roles", you really load it with a list of permissions. So when your application asks "IsInRole()", it does it like this: `bool result = currentPrincipal.IsInRole(requiredPermission);` you can still use `AuthorizeAttribute` to make this work

Comment: Exactly...but the key point is that YOUR internal model should differentiate between roles and permissions, even if the IPrincipal API does not...

Comment: The idea is good. I have no problems building the database and figure the logic out, but I'm rather new to Forms authentication, so I don't know _where_ to put my code... Could you give me some hints there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft's authorization model sucks...and it's widely acknowledged 
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/05/24/dont-do-role-based-authorization-checks-do-activity-based-checks/).

That said. It's nice to have cross compatibility by fitting into their `IPrincipal.IsInRole` API (and thus being able to leverage the `Authorize` attribute)

So...what I do to compromise is have a full permission model in the DB with Users, Roles, and Permissions...but when my code sets the `CurrentPrincipal` I flatten the User's Roles and Permissions into the Roles collection of the `IPrincipal`. It's far from ideal...but IMHO it's a decent compromise. Others (Rockford Lhotka) have also taken this approach: http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/PermissionbasedAuthorizationVsRolebasedAuthorization.aspx

Comment: What would be the best way to solve it? Extend IPrincipal? Change the Stored Procedures? (I don't know why, but currently I cant even use the [Authorize] attribute, even thoug we _are_ using forms authentication)...

Comment: I personally do...but that's not necessary. The thing that's necessary is your code that CREATES the IPrincipal know to flatten your role/permission model into the IPrincipal's roles.