# Multiple ASP.NET Membership roles in the same Website

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3

In my **MVC3 application** I have **ASP.NET Membership roles** like - **Manager, System Admin and Editor**
I am using **Windows Authentication** for the website and I am adding the users in the Network to the Membership just like in the following example -

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx

But, my problem is there are **people who require multiple permissions**. For example

**User-John** is the **Manager of Department-ABC** and he can see all the Actions in Department-ABC.
**User-John** is **also Editor in Department-XYZ** and he should be able to see all the Actions of an Editor in Department-XYZ; 
but **NOT the Actions of Manager**; because **he is not the Manager of Department-XYZ**.

User Mathew is the Manager of Department-XYZ and he is an Editor in Department-ABC.

If I use normal role privileges, it will allow User-John to be the Manager of both departments and it is not right.

My solution is to store the DepartmentID, UserID and RoleID in a seperate table in SQL database and allow according to this table.

How can I get the role ID from ASP.NET Membership in C# and also in SQL?

**Is it safe to do? 
Is there a better solution?**

Comment: It seems that you would benefit from activity based membership. Please read [this](http://ryankirkman.com/2013/01/31/activity-based-authorization.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258512/how-can-i-implement-permission-based-authorization-in-asp-net).

Comment: I have 2 actions like AddMemberToDepartment() and AddComment(). ONLY Manager is allowed to AddMemberToDepartment(). If I give like [Authorize(Roles="Manager")], it will allow both John and Mathew (Mathew is the Manager of Department-XYZ (so he should not be allowed). How can I do it? Will Activity Based Authentication help in it?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity based membership would probably fit here.

In activity based membership your users get access to actions, not to roles. 
Typical usage is:

1. One action = one activity
2. There are still roles given to users, but they are used to group activities
3. There is n..n relation between roles and activities

**Activity** is just a custom action filter that is applied to the action.
Typical example is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/533989/ExtendingplustheplusbehaviorplusofplusMVCplusAutho) (although I don't like this approach, so I made my own implementation).

```
 [Activity(Name="DoSomething")]
 public ActionResult DoSomething()
 {
     ...
     return View();
 }
```

**Membership** can be stored in ASP Membership database table, custom table or represented as AD group. Depends whether you implement custom membership provider or you use default implementation.

At the end, there has to be n..n relationship like **RoleActivity**, where you link the particular role to the activity (like Manager1 to both AddMemberToDepartment and AddComment, and Manager2 to just AddComment). This relation can be classic n..n database relation or 'virtual', where role is in AD and database table relates to it only via group name.

**EDIT:**

If you use default database role based authorization, table aspnet_Roles will be generated for you. To support activity based membership you will have to add your own activity table manualy, along with additional role-activity relation.
This schema should help you proceed.

```
aspnet_Roles (autogenerated)
 * ApplicationId
 * RoleId
 * ...(other autogenerated columns)...

aspnet_MyActivity (add manually)
 * ActivityId
 * ApplicationId
 * Name
 * Description

aspnet_MyPermission (add manually)
 * ApplicationId
 * RoleId
 * ActivityId
```

You can fill roles using membership provider. 
Then fill manually your activities as your application needs them, say, one activity per action method. 
Finally, manually add your activity permissions to roles.

**Real world scenario**

If your organization is small enough, it may be acceptable to add one role per department and one activity per action/deparment:

- role: Dep. mgr. of ABC,
- role: Dep. mgr. of XYZ,
- activity: createAbcUser,
- activity: createXyzUser

Connect them using appropriate permissions and you have your requirement covered.

However, for a large number of departments adding one role per department and giving activity permission for each of them can be a little awkward. In that case you should stick with simple role "Department manager" and simple activity "Create user", and give your manager permission to create user. However, you have to stop manager to create user in a different department - use your hierarchy for that, meaning, check if your user belongs to your manager.

Your action filter will then look like this:

- check if any of current users roles has a permission to run that activity
- check your hierarchy: does your current user have a permission to work on referenced user?

If both of these are true, action method can be executed.

NOTE: You will probably reference user by some input parameter, so your action filter has to access that parameter. See [Getting the values of action parameters within an action filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518827/getting-the-values-of-action-parameters-within-an-action-filter) to solve that.

Comment: Hi,Do we have to create any SQL table to store the activity information? In order to store Roles in SQL table I know we have run aspnet_regsql.exe and it will create the Roles table. I am looking for some nice example to download and play with it. I saw thi code in this link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/533989/ExtendingplustheplusbehaviorplusofplusMVCplusAutho ; could not download the entire project. Many thanks

Comment: You have to persist your activities somehow. You could do it using configuration, text file, even memory, but if there is no special requirement I would stuff them into database table. See updated answer soon.

Comment: I have two users 
User-John:Department Manager of department-ABC and Editor of department XYZ
User-Mathew:Deparmtent Manager of department-XYZ and Editor of deaprtment ABC.Both need access to "ActionResult CreatUser()" when they create a new user; but User-John is allowed to create 
user only for department ABC and user Mathew is allowed only for department XYZ. 
If I add Role-Deparmtne Manager and Action-CreatUser() to aspnet_MyActivity; then both John and Mathew will be able to create users in both departments;
because both of them have role id-Department Manager.
How can I solve it?

Comment: Easy: change scope of your roles. Add two roles: Dep. mgr. of ABC, Dep. mgr. of XYZ. Add two activities: createAbcUser, createXyzUser. Add appropriate permissions. Both activities will probably wrap the same action method, it's perfectly ok.

Comment: Hi, This is not an easy solution. I will have hundreds of department in the website and it is not easy to create roles for each department.

Comment: There is another possibility: use your hierarchical structure of employees to introduce another layer of abstraction that participates in authorization process. I will describe this soon enough - currently we're packing our bags to return from rainy vacation...